# oracle sql - optimize SELECT multiple rows as columns

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, sql-optimization

Here's my table 'extension' which has a reference to 'master' table.

```
MASTER_ID TEXT CATEGORY
1          A1   AA
1          A2   BB
1          A3   CC
```

I need to put these category as columns in my select query, so I have come up with these query:

```
SELECT MASTER_ID,
(SELECT TEXT FROM EXTENSION WHERE CATEGORY = "AA") AS "AATEXT",
(SELECT TEXT FROM EXTENSION WHERE CATEGORY = "BB") AS "BBTEXT",
(SELECT TEXT FROM EXTENSION WHERE CATEGORY = "CC") AS "CCTEXT"

FROM MASTER 
JOIN EXTENSION 
ON MASTER.ID = EXTENSION.MASTER_ID
```

Result:

```
MASTER_ID CATEGORY_1 CATEGORY_2 CATEGORY_3
1         AA         BB         CC
```

It works but performance is an issue.  Any ideas how it can be optimized?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as well formatted text.

Comment: I don't see the `category` table mentioned anywhere in your query.  Do you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, sorry the table is called extension

Comment: Why bother with complex SQL? `select * from extension order by master_id, category` already gets you all you need. You have certainly some GUI where to display the data, e.g. an app with C# showing a grid or a website with PHP filling an HTML table. So loop through the query results and fill the grid.

Comment: @Thorsten sorry.. My query is quite big and complex, this is just one part of it (that I really need to optimize), as you can see this is just an example for simplicity..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the pivot statement to achive this:

```
SELECT * FROM EXTENSION
PIVOT (max(CATEGORY) FOR TEXT
  IN ('A1' AS Category_1, 'A2' AS Category_2, 'A3' AS Category_3))
```

Executing the above query on your data results in the following output:

```
MASTER_ID | CATEGORY_1 | CATEGORY_2 | CATEGORY_3
1         | AA         | BB         | CC
```

This might perform better than your query.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT M.MASTER_ID,
     CASE WHEN E.CATEGORY = 'AA' THEN E.TEXT END AS AATEXT,
     CASE WHEN E.CATEGORY = 'BB' THEN E.TEXT END AS BBTEXT.
     CASE WHEN E.CATEGORY = 'CC' THEN E.TEXT END AS CCTEXT
     FROM MASTER M
     INNER JOIN EXTENSION  E
     ON (M.MASTER.ID = E.EXTENSION.MASTER_ID)
```

You can use this query

Comment: If your values are dynamic, can you tell how you are fetching the dynamic records

Comment: those are just sample values.. these can't be hardcoded as these are dynamic and many..

Comment: the text field value is from a user input on the application

Comment: From where you are getting the dynamic value, the hardcoded values ?

Comment: it is saved in the 'text' column on 'extension' table from a user input from the application.. so it can be anything

Comment: Then instead of hardcoded values you can write a select query to select the data from another table. Eg: CASE WHEN E.CATEGORY =(SELECT T.TEXT_COLUMN FROM TABLE NAME T WHERE E.FOREIGN_KEY = T.FOREIGN_KEY) THEN E.TEXT END AS T.TEXT_COLUMN